# iPad UIInterfaceRotation is 0, rotation messed up on app-start

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, autorotate, uideviceorientation

i guess i missed something really important in the apple manuals which causes me having this problems.

I will describe what i want to have and what i get instaed + what i do.

**Preamble:**

- goal of my work is a app having a login-screen. this screen is supposed to be placed ontop of all other views, to fade out later. so in this case i guess i already break a rule, in case i understood that "only-one-main-window-guideline" correctly.

**What i want:**

- having an universal application √ check
- having an universal application which has UIInterfaceRotation for iPad only √ check
- not having troubles regarding uiinterfaceorientation or uideviceorientation on startup allowing me to show all views in proper dimension without having to rotate a few times to have it all properly positioned. - not checked

**What i get:**

- when i start the app in landscape, which is default orientation from my views in interface-Builder, its perfeclty aligned and i can rotate all i want, its perfect, stays perfefct, hooray
- when i start the app in portrait, i see the landscape-views flying around on the screen - each time on diffrent pace - at least that seems like. when i rotate the app now, forth and back, its all aligned as it should - also perfectly as wanted.

**What i do:**

- 99% of all rotation-related settings is made in interface builder, i currently just have some did-change-methods to change background-images when rotation is done and so on.

i noticed, that even when i build the screen after device knows its orientation, it leads to this.

so in other words:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
      [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
      [self addEventListener:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification sel:@selector(buildScreen)];
       ....
```

note: addEventListener is a small notification-category i created for easier handling. so no magic in here.

in build-screen i add all subviews.
at first, the actualy screen in the background, this screen will get the login as subview (which does not matter since when i add login to main-window itself, situation is the same).

So in this case, i really dont know what do do next.
Once orientation-alignment is setup, it all fits perfectly as i defined in IB.

Any help, links, code, etc, appreciated. thank you very much! i tried searching for this, just found many similar problems, no solutions. so a little sorry in case i seem to ask the very same question, a big one if i really do.

Best Regards

Comment: You should be fine with a login screen.  Though it might be better to present it as a modal window if you are not currently doing so.  As for the orientation problem, are you creating your views in the `viewDidLoad` section of their corresponding files?  If so, moving most of that to the `viewDidAppear:` method should fix the problem because it sounds to me that it's trying to build a view before the view has a chance to initialize

Comment: thank you slev, but this only leads to no-rotation on startup at all, so when i start simulator down under, defaultpng is ok, application is down under as well. when i rotate, all becomes good again. also, the device-statusbar is at bottom then,

Comment: No-rotation on startup in what way?  Meaning it is in portrait rather than landscape?  Sorry if they seem like dumb questions.  Just trying to understand better what's going on.  But if that's the case and it starts in portrait, you should be able to manually change it to landscape from within the code

Comment: no question is dump, nor is yours. ;) in the way you described, the app starts in landscape only - which is the default setup.  how do i change orientation manually? did not know that is possible w/o CGATransform..

Comment: I apologize for the huge gap in time here, haha.  My app just got approved yesterday, so I've been too busy telling anyone I knew and haven't been on the computer.  Anyway, back to the situation at hand.  I believe you can change your orientation manually using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:someOrientation];`.  I have a feeling this may be a slightly glitchy fix, but it should (though I have yet to test it to make sure) force the application into the orientation you want

Comment: haha slev, no need to apologize at all - i appreciate your will to help me out! :)   the problem is, setOrientation - how can it help me to figure out, what to set, when i first need to know in which orientation the device is? My problem is: the app starts, _after_ device knows orientation, i set the screens. this is a mini-gap from launching, but it works. the problem is, that i add view A, which aligs due to IB, on top i set View B which does NOT. so it is placed anyahere in the screen, when i rotate it aligns. it must align before i rotate.. does this make it a bit more clear?

Comment: That does make it more clear, yes.  When is View B created?  And from where?  This sounds very similar to when you create a modal view from a viewController before the viewController has loaded fully.  This causes the second view to try and align itself based on a position that hasn't been determined, which gives it a funky look.  Hopefully this is the case, because the fix is simple.  You just create the second view from the first view's `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`, giving the view enough time to find its correct coordinates

Comment: Similarly, if the second view is based off the template from IB for the first view, you may need to introduce an offset.  For some reason, you don't have the same concrete coordinates in each orientation when they are switched.  I never really figured out why this happens, but have had to deal with this in my own app in several occasions

Comment: Hey slev, thank you so much! i just fixed it a diffrent way tough - but thanks a lot for your time and ideas! My final fix was, to create a 2nd xib with portrait mode, load the proper xib on start - and the n i did some ugly pass-thorughts from willRotate/willAnimateRotation .. to that View, to realign all contents. now its working! :) Again, thanks for time and thougts!! :) i owe you one!

Comment: ah, show me your app! :)

Comment: My pleasure.  I'm glad you got it fixed up.  Ugly or not, that will definitely do the trick.  And at least now you can move on =].  My app is Survey Assistant if you want to check it out (or know anyone that might be able to use it).  It's iPad only, but I'm trying to get rid of pen and paper for the marketing/polling field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a proper solution, so i used `multiple-xib` files to get it done. It's annoying but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't normally recommend this because i think it's annoying as a user, but you could try the Info.plist setting

```
Initial interface orientation
```

and set this to the Landscape if this is what works for you.

Could be a temporary workaround. I recon your issues are much more complex though than a simple suggestive fix.

Comment: i am afraid it does not work, since each and every view has to be rotateable. thanks

Comment: This doesn't fix your orientation for the life of the app. It's just for startup.